# yarn install occured with error: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\

Tags: linux, npm, installation, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run project as git clone with yarn install => yarn dev..... after yarn install I get this error error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@xxxxxxxxx/common/1.38.0/aaaaaaaaaaaaaa: Request failed "401 Unauthorized"". Working in Ubuntu 22.04. Do someone know how to fix it? Thanks everyone.

I've tried:
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
yarn clear cache
reinstall node with npm
I have my .npmrc file with PAT (scope: read pcgs)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.